# django rest api - adding users to keyword model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

i want to implement a feature in my rest api that users can add specific keywords for a news feed.

so if the users make a post request with a keyword within, the user object will be added on the predefined keyword (predefined in the database).

I have tried it with this code, but always if i try to simulate the post request with postman and i have this problem:

the keyword will be added but not the provided json data, its just a empty string and the post request returns also an empty keyword...

I hope you are able to help me and maybe you could give me an advice how to just allow the static keywords which are already defined and allow user only have a keyword once (no double keywords with same value)

Made with this headers:

```html
[{"key":"Content-Type","value":"application/json","description":""}]
[{"key":"Authorization","value":"Token xxxxxxx","description":""}]

Body:
{
"name": "keyword1"
}
```

Authorization works, so the user added to the empty keyword

I am very new to django and i am doing this project to improve my skills, so please be lenient to me :) So it could be that its completly wrong, please give me some advices to solve my problem

These are the snippets for the implementation:

models.py

```python
class Keywords(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serializers.py

```python
class KeywordSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Keywords
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'user')

    def create(self, validated_data):
            keyword = Keywords(**validated_data)
            keyword.save()
            keyword.user.add(self.context['request'].user)
            return keyword
```

views.py

```python
class KeywordAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, ]
    serializer_class = KeywordSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        keyword = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "name": KeywordSerializer(keyword, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
        })
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "the keyword will be added but not the provided json data"? Is it just adding a keyword where `name` is an empty string? Also, try to print `request.data` in your `post` method to see what the name is in the raw data.

Comment: @slider if i add a user to a specific keyword with the json data {„name“:“keyword1“} in the post request then django saves only an empty string as the keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```
class KeywordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = Keywords
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = validated_data.pop('user')
        kw = Keywords.objects.create(**validated_data)
        kw.user.add(user)
        kw.save()
        return kw
```

and `views`:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions

class KeywordAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, ]
    serializer_class = KeywordSerializer
    queryset = Keywords.objects.all()
```

The input payload be as

```
{
"name":"kw1"
}
```

**NOTE**
Here I used **ModelSerializer** class, because it's very handy for `CURD` applications and `HiddenField` is something like `write_only=True` parameter for fields.

References:

1. [DRF - Modelviewset](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)
2. [HiddenField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#hiddenfield)
3. [CurrentUserDefault](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault)

Comment: okay my that was my fault, your solution is correct, thank you very much! i learned much about it now

Comment: @marc_s I don't understand why you edited my answer, and I think it's irrelevant here

Comment: I fixed a glaring typo - one that I've found in almost all your responses - it's **references** - with just one **f** (not two, as you keep using). And I removed all those unnecessary `<br>` tags, too - just trying to make things nicer, smoother, less riddled with typos etc.

Comment: I understood my typos. Thanks for that. But I'm not feeling good with your *code snippet editing*. I wish to emphasize some line so I made those lines **bold**. After your *code cleaning*,  some of the tags are still there...which is not good.

Comment: @marc_s In short, Please revert those **code snippet** formatting because I really think that `code lines with **bold** format` are necessary

Answer (score 1):

There are few things you are doing wrong

**First**
Your model's name is `Keywords` it shouldn't be plural use `Keyword` and `user` field is ManyToMany so you should pluralise it

```
class Keyword(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Second**
You are using `Serializer` instead of `ModelSerializer`

```
class KeywordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Keywords
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'users')
        read_only_fields = ('users',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        keyword = super().create(validated_data)
        keyword.users.add(self.context['request'].user)
        return keyword
```

**Third**
You don't have to write creation logic yourself use existing mixins

```
from rest_framework import mixins


class KeywordAPI(mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, ]
    serializer_class = KeywordSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hello, i tried your solution but i get a error that POST Method is not allowed. I tried to add     def post(self, request, format=None):
        return Response("ok"), but he does not create any keywords

Answer (score 0):

For those who maybe have the same problem, here is the whole solution:
Thanks to Sardorbek Imomaliev and Jerin Peter George for helping me

serializer:

```
class KeywordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
users = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

class Meta:
    model = Keyword
    fields = '__all__'

def create(self, validated_data):
    users = validated_data.pop('users')
    if Keyword.objects.filter(**validated_data).exists():
        kw = Keyword.objects.filter(**validated_data).get()
        kw.users.add(self.context['request'].user)
        return kw
    else:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("This Keyword has not been set yet.")
```

model:

```
class Keyword(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

view:

```
class KeywordAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, ]
serializer_class = KeywordSerializer
queryset = Keyword.objects.all()
```